# put(int,int,int) method in Mat>OpenCv in java

Tags: java, opencv

thank you for your help 
i am go to write a code for edge detection in java , i get prewitt edge detection code from [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/applying_prewitt_operator.htm) link ,when i just paste this to one class , program runs perfect.
but when i paste this code to one method in other program ,the error is occur.

error say that :
The method put(int, int, double[]) in the type Mat is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int) 
i became confused , why this code independently runs correct , but when i paste this to one method of other program....

```
public BufferedImage edgePrewitt(File arg){
    BufferedImage out1 = null;
    try {

         int kernelSize = 9;
         System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );

         Mat source = Imgcodecs.imread(arg.getAbsolutePath(), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
         Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());

         Mat kernel = new Mat(kernelSize,kernelSize, CvType.CV_8UC1);
         int[][] data=new int[][]{{-1,0,1},{-1,0,1},{-1,0,1}}; 
         for(int row=0;row<3;row++){
               for(int col=0;col<3;col++){
                   kernel.put(row   , col   , data[row][col]);
                   System.out.println(data[row][col]);
               }
            }

         Imgproc.filter2D(source, destination, -1, kernel);
         Imgcodecs.imwrite("output.jpg", destination);
         out1 = mat2Img(destination);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
    return out1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the method `put` (class `org.opencv.core.Mat`) is:

`put(int, int, double[])`

`put(int, int, byte[])`

`put(int, int, int[])`

`put(int, int, short[])`

`put(int, int, float[])`

[documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.friendularity/org.friendularity.bundle.jvision/1.0.0/org/opencv/core/Mat.java)

Note that all methods signature, the third parameter is an array.

Try the follow:

```
public BufferedImage edgePrewitt(File arg){
    BufferedImage out1 = null;
    try {

         int kernelSize = 9;
         System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );

         Mat source = Imgcodecs.imread(arg.getAbsolutePath(), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
         Mat destination = new Mat(source.rows(),source.cols(),source.type());

         Mat kernel = new Mat(kernelSize,kernelSize, CvType.CV_8UC1);
         int[][] data=new int[][]{{-1,0,1},{-1,0,1},{-1,0,1}}; 
         for(int row=0;row<3;row++){
            kernel.put(row   , col   , data[row]);
         }

         Imgproc.filter2D(source, destination, -1, kernel);
         Imgcodecs.imwrite("output.jpg", destination);
         out1 = mat2Img(destination);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
    return out1;
}
```

Comment: thank you , that problem is solved , but again in "col" parameter in for loop is not defined :/